# Ubuntu, shopsys install via composer, docker, still crashing

Tags: docker, ubuntu, composer-php

I wanna install shopsys via composer and docker, as is recommended.

https://github.com/shopsys/shopsys/blob/master/docs/installation/installation-using-docker-linux.md

I installed git, php-fpm (configured), postgres (configured), composer, docker, docker-compose.

```
sudo apt install git
sudo apt install php7.2-fpm
sudo apt install postgresql
sudo apt install composer
sudo apt install docker-ce
sudo apt install docker-compose
```

Everything ok.

I added my user to docker group.

```
sudo usermod -a -G docker $(whoami)
```

Ok.

Next I made folder **/var/www/html/shopsys**, created project shopsys via composer.

```
composer create-project shopsys/project-base --no-install --keep-vcs
cd project-base/
```

Then I run this in **/var/www/html/shopsys/project-base**.

```
./scripts/install.sh
```

Everything seems to be ok, until this.

```
[RuntimeException]                                             
/var/www/html/vendor does not exist and could not be created.
```

I set rights to 777 for folder **/var/www/html**, and run it again, but same problem.

The I run this.

```
sudo composer install
```

It shows me this error.

```
....Exception\InvalidConfigurationException]
Invalid configuration for path "monolog.handlers.main": You can only use ex    
cluded_http_codes/excluded_404s with a FingersCrossedHandler definition

In ScriptHandler.php line 294:

An error occurred when executing the "'shopsys:domains-urls:configure'" command:
In BaseNode.php line 319:

...\Exception\InvalidConfigurationException]
Invalid configuration for path "monolog.handlers.main": You can only use ex                                                                                                                                     
cluded_http_codes/excluded_404s with a FingersCrossedHandler definition
...
```

etc., error is quite ugly.

Last error when i run script **install.sh**.

```
file_put_contents(/var/www/html/vendor/composer/installed.json): failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

But this folder does not exist.

```
ls: cannot access '/var/www/html/vendor/': No such file or directory
```

Just question, where could be the problem?

**Is possible to download sources from some link, extract it, configure and display in web browser with easy way, for example as wordpress?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

### To solve problem with vendor:

It seems that your UID and GID is different than default 1000, that is set in docker-compose.yml for Linux by default.

To solve your issue you can continue by step 3 in https://github.com/shopsys/shopsys/blob/master/docs/installation/installation-using-docker-linux.md#3-set-the-uid-and-gid-to-allow-file-access-in-mounted-volumes

You found issue with installation script, I have created [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/shopsys/shopsys/issues/1150).

### To solve problem with Invalid configuration for path "monolog.handlers.main":

Currently there is problem with new minor version (3.4.0) of [symfony/monolog-bundle](https://github.com/symfony/monolog-bundle) that created BC break. There is already created [issue](https://github.com/symfony/monolog-bundle/issues/309) about this problem and there is already merged [fix](https://github.com/shopsys/shopsys/pull/1148) in Shopsys master.

To solve problem in your project you have to add 
`"symfony/monolog-bundle": ">=3.4.0",` in `conflict` section in your `composer.json` file and then run `composer install` again.

*We are trying to answer questions on stackoverflow as soon as possible, but we also have [Slack](http://slack.shopsys-framework.com) where is many users and you might get your question answered much faster.*

Comment: About problem with vendor, quite weird, because if I set chmod 777 to html folder, it should not be affected, because everybody has rights to create everuthing in this folder.